# TF one hot encode tensor object

Tags: tensorflow

Running a simple logistic regression following the mnist simple example
my code:

```
x = np.array(xHotdog + xNotHotdog)
y = np.array(yHotdog + yNotHotdog)

print("y shape before: "+str(y.shape))
y = tf.one_hot(indices=y, depth=2)
print("y shape after: "+str(y.shape))    
y.eval()
return x,y
```

Later I run:

```
sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_ys})
```

Getting the error:

> TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object.
>   Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy
>   ndarrays, or TensorHandles.For reference, the tensor obje ct was
>   Tensor("one_hot:0", shape=(6457, 2), dtype=float32) which was passed
>   to the feed with key Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(?, 2),
>   dtype=float32).

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `Tensor object` to feed_dict and it raise an error. As mentioned in [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run):

> The optional **feed_dict** argument allows the caller to **override the**
>   **value** of tensors in the graph.
>
> **feed_dict**: A dictionary that maps graph **elements to values**

So you need some values for the feed_dict. As shown in the error:

> Acceptable feed values include Python **scalars**, **strings**, **lists**, **numpy**
>   **ndarrays**, or **TensorHandles**

**Option 1**: In your case you pass `Tensor object` which cause such exception. The issue can resolve in this way:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="Y")
y = tf.one_hot(indices=y, depth=2)
...

sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_ys})
```

---

**Option 2**: You can also evaluate the value with (in this case feed_dict not needed):

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, [20])
b = tf.one_hot(a, depth=10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(a)
    print(sess.run([b]))
```

Comment: I didn't understand what I should change. Your suggestion looks exactly like the code I wrote?

Comment: @JY2k I wrote two different options. I think the first one would fix your probelm

Comment: I needed to evaluate within a session